# remove file extension from url in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect, server, file-extension

I have a project where I have two subfolders for two different languages. example.com/en and /ku.
I want to remove .html extensions for all files in both subfolders from .htaccess file with this code:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

however, I get 404 not found in my console whenever I request something like example.com/en/index
this happens no matter where I put the the .htaccess file(root, inside bot subfolders)

don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Your rule looks like it should work. Are you sure the htaccess  is enabled on your server?

Comment: This happens only on my local server. I'm on macOS Bug Sur I don't know how to enable that on local server. it should be noted that I'm using liveserver extension on vsCode